# MATLAB: If this value of 5x5 cell with vectors [106x1] are different to zeroes,count them e put the count in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, compare, cell

I have matchcounts (5x5)cell, every cell has a vector of double [106x1]. The vectors of double have zeros and non zero values. I want to find non zero values for every cell, count them and put the result in a matrix.
I tried with this code:

```
a{i,j}(k,1)=[];

for k=1:106

    for i=1:5
        for j=1:5
            if (matchcounts{i,j}(k,1))~=0
                a{i,j}=a{i,j}(k,1)+1;
            end
        end
    end 
end
```

and others but it's not correct! Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: From you description I do not understand what your code is supposed to do. Could you give a small example of input and expected output?

Comment: I try to explain better. The code have to count the element no zero of the vectors in the cell; after the count it put the count in a matrix. For example:  matchcounts{1,1}(k,1) has 30 no zero values. I want to put 30 in a matrix A in position (1,1). So A(1,1)=30

Comment: Is there any possibility to get a "2" in your output matrix?

Comment: Do you have to use cell arrays? I think you should use a single matrix for `matchcounts` and `a` instead.

Comment: no, because in the output matrix I want the number of non zero values for every cell. The output matrix is 5x5 and contains the number of no zero values of matchcounts{5x5}(k,1)

Comment: Previous code is: [digits{1:2}] = ndgrid(0:4);
matchcounts = cell(size(digits{1}));
for k = 1:numel(matchcounts)
    matchstarts = regexp(TrajCompact, sprintf('%d.+?%d', digits{1}(k), digits{2}(k)));
    matchcounts{k} = cellfun(@numel,matchstarts);
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to fix your answer above, I recommend to change the data structure to have a much simpler solution possible. Instead of having a 2D cell array which holds 1D data, choose a single 3D data structure.

For an optimal solution you would change your previous code code to directly write the 3D-matrix, instead of converting it. To get started, this code converts it so you can already see how the data structure should look like:

```
%convert to matrix
for idx=1:numel(matchcounts)
    matchcounts{idx}=permute(matchcounts{idx},[3,2,1]);
end
matchcounts=cell2mat(matchcounts);
```

And finding the nonzero elements:

```
a=(matchcounts~=0)
```

To index the result, instead of `a{k,l}(m,1)` you use `a(k,l,m)`

To give you some rule to avoid complicated data structures in the future. Use cell arrays only for string data and data of different size. Whenever you have a cell array which contains only vectors or matrices of the same size, it should be a multidimensional matrix.

Comment: thanks! Your answer is very helpful. After i use counter=sum(a(:,:,:),3); and find the matrix that I want!